# compare list size of storages with yesterday in linux by python

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux

I must check our storage size every morning.
The routine is that I connect to the Linux server every day (via ssh). And then with the command "df -h" I see the storage list and write the change compared to yesterday in an excel file. I wanted to see if there was a way for this comparison to be done automatically via a code.
I have to check each of these storages every day. for example I must check following storage and if it increase inform others.

[image: Storage]

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: @balderman ,So I put the result of this command in the text file (df -h > STORAGE.txt) and then put it in a excel then start to compare with yesterday file. I think this isn't optimal way.

Comment: start by implementing a CRON job that will append to a file the result of `df -h`